# Error message when pasting Math into answer

Tags: bug, user-interface

If I am starting to type an answer and copy/paste some MathJax from the question, I often get the error message saying I have to have 30 characters in my answer and I only have xx.  I haven't asked to post the answer yet, and don't intend to until I have well more than 30.  Can this be fixed?

Added:  It seems to come up any time I have started to type an answer and click away for some reason.  It can be to visit another web page, to copy something (doesn't have to be MathJax), or whatever.  I haven't tried to post the answer yet-usually I am in the process of composing it.

Comment: I had those as well.

Comment: Hm, I thought they were something that popped up automatically as soon as one started typing and would routinely disappear when enough text has been entered. I can't reproduce it at all anymore, though.

Comment: It happened to me yesterday as well; I was clicking on the "this post was edited" message to see what edits were made, and I got that message.